# Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes when all of my quotes are single quotes

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am trying to execute this piece of code which should successfully convert my json string to a proper dict file since apparently the requests libary needs it to be formatted this way...

```
import json


Headers="""{
":authority":"coinmarketcap.com",
":method":"POST",
":path":"/login",
":scheme":"https",
"accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cache-control":"max-age=0",
"content-length":"743",
"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"cookie":\""""+CookieDough+"""\",
"origin":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"referer":"https://coinmarketcap.com",
"upgrade-insecure-requests":"1",
"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36", 
}"""

print(json.loads(Headers))
```

However when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Master\Documents\CoinMarketCapScraperTool\CoinMarketCapScraperTool", line 39, in <module>
    print(json.loads(Headers))
  File "C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 17 column 1 (char 1132)
```

I also attempted to run the first Headers variable but with \" added at the beggining and end of the string. However It gave me the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

However when I add

```
strict=False
```

to it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Im going mad please help me out lol

Comment: You've got a trailing comma after the last key (`"user-agent"`); JSON does not allow that.

Comment: Even after removing it I still obtain AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' on 
print(json.load(Headers, strict=False))

Comment: There are separate methods for loading JSON from a string (`loads`) and a file-like object (`load`). When you get the "'str' object has no attribute 'read'` error, that means you called the wrong one, passing a string to the file parser.

Comment: First of all thanks for pointing that out since i didnt know what it did and i was originally using loads but switched to load in desperation of finding a solution. However even after doing this change I still recieve: 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 2 (char 4)

Comment: This loads without issue in Py2.7 once you remove the trailing comma...

Comment: Hmm interesting, I am on Py3.6.4, running it on the sublimetext builder EDIT: Same error when I run it directly from the cmd

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to pass those headers in the `requests.get()` method,  why aren't you directly passing them as `headers=Headers` without the string quotes (`"""..."""`) around them?